# Velocity array not working when array has empty values

Tags: arrays, velocity

I have the following code:

```
#set ($recsList = [$entity1,$entity2,entity3,entity4])
  #foreach($article in $recsList)
  <li>
    Entity # $velocityCount in $article.id<br/>
  </li>
#end
```

In my recsList only entity1 and 2 has a value, 3 and 4 are empty. Now, the above isn't working because entity3 and 4 in my recsList doesn't have a value. If I limit recsList to only entity1 and 2, then it is working just fine.

I've tried solving it by creating a new array only with products that has .id set:

```
#set ($displayRecs=[])
#foreach($article in $recsList)
  #if($article.id!="")
    $displayRecs.add($displayRecs.size(), $article)
  #end                    
#end
```

But it still requires that recsList only contains the entity that has value listed.

Is there any way I can get it to work when having entity listed in recsList that doesn't have values?

Comment: Should this be tagged java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **quiet reference notation**:

```
#set ($recsList = ["$!entity1","$!entity2","$!entity3","$!entity4"])
  #foreach($article in $recsList)
  <li>
    Entity # $velocityCount in $article.id<br/>
  </li>
#end
```

This way, missing values will appear as empty strings.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to solve it. Doing so gives me the following error: Error: Failed to parse template code: message=[Error in page - invalid reference. ] syntax=[$article.id]